# Why is updateQueryData from RTK query not updating my state?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, immer.js

I'm using RTK query and I want to overwrite the state with the result from my transform request. I get my overview of a todos array by calling the getTodosOverview Query. After that I call a updateTodos query and this gives me back a new array with todos. I want to overwrite the original array with these results. I'm using the function **updateQueryData** but it doesnt seem to work. What am I missing here?

```
export const todosApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'todosApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'api/todos' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getToDosOverview: builder.query<Array<ToDos>, string>({
        query: () => `getOverview`,
        transformResponse: (rawResult: { data: Array<ToDos> }) => rawResult.data,
        keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
      }),
      updateTodos: builder.mutation<Array<ToDos>, string>({
        query: (fileId) => ({
          url: `updateTodos?fileId=${fileId}`,
          method: 'POST',
        }),
        transformResponse: (rawResult: { data: Array<ToDos> }) => rawResult.data,
        async onQueryStarted(uniqueIdentifier, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
          const { data }= await queryFulfilled;
          // Update state with new data from response
          const patchResult = dispatch(
            todosApi.util.updateQueryData(
              'getToDosOverview',
              uniqueIdentifier,
              () => {
                return data;
              }
            )
          );
        },
      }),
    }),
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not returning anything new.

```js
          const patchResult = dispatch(
            todosApi.util.updateQueryData(
              'getToDosOverview',
              uniqueIdentifier,
              // here you are getting the old state as a variable called `ToDos`
              (ToDos: Array<ToDos>) => {
                // and here you return that old state without any change
                return ToDos;
              }
            )
          );
```

Also, you are doing that way before you have even received a response.

The response will be available after the line

```js
await queryFulfilled;
```

so you probably want to do something like

```js
const { data } = await queryFulfilled
```

and then use `data` as the new value.

Generally, it seems like you are copy-pasting from the "optimistic updates" example. Please look at the example of [pessimistic updates](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates#pessimistic-updates) instead.

Also, with your code you are using the wrong argument if you want to update `useGetToDosOverviewQuery()`.
You are updating `useGetToDosOverviewQuery(uniqueIdentifier)` here.

You should probably call

```
todosApi.util.updateQueryData('getToDosOverview', undefined, ...)
```

Comment: i have updated my code in the description and also I also done the same update in my application but still it doesnt get overwritten

Comment: You are updating `useGetToDosOverviewQuery(uniqueIdentifier)` here, not `useGetToDosOverviewQuery()` with your code. Do you maybe want to `todosApi.util.updateQueryData('getToDosOverview', undefined, ...)` ?

Comment: Hey thanks! that indeed worked, when matching the second parameter with the arg from the getTodosOverview it worked! if u post it as an answer i can complete it. so i adapted:  "getToDosOverview: builder.query<Array<ToDos>, string>({" to "getToDosOverview: builder.query<Array<ToDos>, undefined>({"   and then "todosApi.util.updateQueryData(
              'getToDosOverview',uniqueIdentifier   to todosApi.util.updateQueryData(
              'getToDosOverview', undefined

Comment: I edited it at the end of my answer.

Comment: How to achieve this if you have dynamic arguments in getToDosOverview?

Comment: @Gaccho you will have to call that with the exact arguments used for the query instead of `undefined` - for every cache entry you want to update.

Comment: @phry Thanks. And if you want to update only the latest cache entry? Should save those dynamic arguments in a state to access them in `updateQueryData`?

Comment: @Gaccho For RTK-Q itself, there is no concept of a "latest" cache entry - assume you have three components all rendered at the same time calling useSomethingQuery with different arguments - there is not really a "last" one, the order in which they render can be completely random. So yes, you would have to save those arguments that are of interest for you in the store.